# What colour is Pac-Man?

Tags: pac-man

For a recent art project I needed to colour in Pacman using an RGB colour code. A quick google only returned [this page](http://www.colourlovers.com/color/FFEE00/Pac-Man_Yellow) (with no information) and several discussions elsewhere about what paint to use. I've had a look at google images and have seen some where he looks almost orange.

So, is there a definitive answer to what colour Pacman is? Has his colour changed over time?

Comment: He's yellow.  If you want an exact RGB color, that's what an eyedropper is for, not Arqade.

Answer (score 6):

In answer to your second question first, his color has changed over time due to various hardware constraints and artistic license. The original game has been re-released at least twenty times on platforms ranging from the Atari 2600 to Windows Phone 7, showing up as white, yellow, orange, and even grey:

[image: Apple II]

[image: ColecoVision]

[image: GameBoy]

As for the original Arcade machine, he was yellow. A quick use of the eye dropper with Microsoft Paint says the RGB values are 252, 234, and 63 respectively.

[image: Arcade]